# UIWebView: How is baseURL for loadHTMLString or loadData methods supposed to work?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Due to some major issues with caching in the UIWebView, I'm requesting an HTML page myself and loading it into the web view using the following method:

```
-(void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType
        textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

Previously, I've been setting the`baseURL` to `nil` since all resources were defined with absolute URLs. I found 1 relative link, and rather than try to guarantee that all resources in the future have absolute paths, I thought it would be better to specify base URL. When I try doing that, the web view loads the base URL instead of the NSData.

There isn't much in Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for base URL. What's the expected behavior here?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume this corresponds to the [HTML base tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4), but it's strange that it would load the wrong page. Are you sure your page doesn't have some redirection scripts or something?

Comment: @jtbandes, you're definitely onto something. I had problems before with resources pointing back to the page, (e.g. `<img src="" />`). I couldn't find any of those issues in this case. I solved my problem by adding the `<base href="{url}"></base>` tag to the head _after_ page load by injecting JS. This only works because all page resources on load use absolute paths, not relative ones.

Comment: @jtbandes, I believe that `baseURL:` is unfortunately _not_ the same as the HTML base tag. I think `baseURL:` simply means "assume this string came from a file called `baseURL`". It took me 2 hours of debugging today to reach that conclusion. It seems like @goldierox has the right idea of having to use both `baseURL` and `<base>`.

Comment: Seriously, Apple, this could be better documented. </rant>